# Can't get calories from google fit HistoryApi

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I use HistoryApi to get calories expended,but I can't get any data.
My request code like this :

```
private DataReadRequest queryFitnessData() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
    Log.i(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));  

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED,DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    return readRequest;

}
```

and this is my error log :
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C93nG.png)

Please help me !!!

Thanks you.

Comment: I solved this problem

Comment: Because the start time and end time setting in question

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can post the entire code. There is nowhere online with the calories count code

Comment: Calories fetching here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285508/calories-for-session-google-fit/41789675#41789675