# calories for session - google fit

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm trying to get the burned calories for an inserted google fit session as soon as I've inserted them. Thus, is ther any possibility to calculate the burned calories for a session`?

Right now I create my session, insert it to google fit and then it takes at least 5 minutes till the burned calories for the activity are readable from google fit again.

Looking forward for your ideas and thanks in advance!

Juliane

Answer (score 2):

**Calories for session**

```
 private class BackgroundFetching extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                Date now = new Date();
                cal.setTime(now);
                long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -cal.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -cal.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -cal.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));
                long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

                Log.i(TAG, "Session Start Time: " + android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", startTime));
                Log.i(TAG, "Session  End Time: " + android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", endTime));

                DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                       .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                        .enableServerQueries()
                        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build();

                DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                        Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                SendData(dataReadResult);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error msg: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

 private static void SendDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
        try {

            for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                    if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Field.FIELD_CALORIES.getName())) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        object.put("calories", dp.getValue(field));
                        object.put("start_time", dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                        object.put("end_time", dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

**Full Demo with calories ,heart rate and foot steps**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "IWatch";
    private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private OnDataPointListener mListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        initializeLogging();
        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        } else {
            buildFitnessClient();
        }
    }

    private void buildFitnessClient() {

        // we will use one listener
        mListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
                for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                    Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                    Log.d(TAG, "DataPoint " + field.getName() + " = " + val);
                }
            }
        };
        if (mClient == null && checkPermissions()) {
            mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ))
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
                    .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
                    .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                    .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(
                            new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                                @Override
                                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                                    subscribeToFetching();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                    if (i == ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                    } else if (i
                                            == ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    )
                    .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            Snackbar.make(
                                    MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_view),
                                    "Exception while connecting to Google Play services: " +
                                            result.getErrorMessage(),
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .build();
        }
    }

    private void subscribeToFetching() {
        new BackgroundFetching().execute();
    }

    private class BackgroundFetching extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                Date now = new Date();
                cal.setTime(now);
                long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -cal.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -cal.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -cal.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));
                long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

                Log.i(TAG, "Start Time: " + android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", startTime));
                Log.i(TAG, "End Time: " + android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", endTime));

                DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
                        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                        .enableServerQueries()
                        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build();

                DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                        Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                SendData(dataReadResult);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error msg: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void SendData(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

                if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
                    for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
                        List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                        for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                            SendDataSet(dataSet, array);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned DataSets is: "
                            + dataReadResult.getDataSets().size());
                    for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
                        SendDataSet(dataSet, array);
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, ""
                        + array.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUI, 10000); // 10 second
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateUI); // 10 second
    }

    private static void SendDataSet(DataSet dataSet, JSONArray array) {
        try {

            for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                    if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Field.FIELD_CALORIES.getName())) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        object.put("calories", dp.getValue(field));
                        object.put("start_time", dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                        object.put("end_time", dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                        array.put(object);
                    }
                    if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Field.FIELD_STEPS.getName())) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        object.put("steps", dp.getValue(field));
                        object.put("start_time", dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                        object.put("end_time", dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                        array.put(object);
                    }
                    if (field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Field.FIELD_BPM.getName())) {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        object.put("bpm", dp.getValue(field));
                        object.put("start_time", dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                        object.put("end_time", dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                        array.put(object);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private final Runnable mUpdateUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            subscribeToFetching();
        }
    };


    private void initializeLogging() {
        LogWrapper logWrapper = new LogWrapper();
        Log.setLogNode(logWrapper);
        MessageOnlyLogFilter msgFilter = new MessageOnlyLogFilter();
        logWrapper.setNext(msgFilter);
        LogView logView = (LogView) findViewById(R.id.sample_logview);
        logView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.Log);
        logView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        msgFilter.setNext(logView);
        Log.i(TAG, "Ready");
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int permissionState1 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionState1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.main_activity_view),
                    R.string.permission_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
                                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildFitnessClient();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(
                        findViewById(R.id.main_activity_view),
                        R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction(R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Dont forget to add permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
```